# FB API: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

I'm using FBJS to post photo

```
FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
      message: 'some message',
      url: 'some url'
     }, function(response){
            if (!response || response.error) {
                /*some error alert*/
            else {
                /*some success*/
            }
     }
 });
```

Almost, it works fine, but OCCASIONALLY, it shows error alert.
I see on Console, it says: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

How to deal with it?
I've tried some solutions (such as Content-Type, script type...) but it still does not works in SOME times :(

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

headers: [
          { "name":"Content-Type", 
            "value":"text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"}
       ]

If it is only occasional, maybe you're hitting an API call limit and it's returning an error? Check that the data is correct, even if it is getting an error. Use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)  to get more clear diagnostic results.

Comment: I just tried this, I still don't meet error again, but I'm not sure this is final solution. I'll try more and notice you when error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

I had that problem and in my case the reason was local - the "Disconnect" Chrome addon, that was blocking requests to facebook, I just forgot that I had it installed.